# How can I get a list of content types with drush?

Tags: drush

How can I get the existing content type list with drush? This will allow me to quickly produce a list.

I've tried with:

```
$ drush @d6 @sites genc --types
```

But I need the `devel_generates` module enabled for this.

> Command genc needs the following module(s) enabled to run: devel_generate.

Comment: the easiest way is to open admin/structure/types

Comment: Why don't you enable it then?

Comment: because this module doesn't give  a list of content types..actually i do it by copy/paste list from admin/content/types/list

Comment: genc is used from devel_generate to generate new content, this wont show you existing content types.

Comment: there is this function: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.module/function/node_get_types/6

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try the following commands.

#### Drupal 7 & 8

```
drush ev "print_r(array_keys(node_type_get_types()));"
```

#### Drupal 5 & 6

```
drush ev "print_r(array_keys(node_get_types()));"
```

Answer (score 13):

List of names:

`drush sqlq "SELECT name FROM node_type;"`

List of machine names:

`drush sqlq "SELECT type FROM node_type;"`

This works in D6 and D7.

The first line of the command's output will be `name` or `type`, respectively.
Pipe `|tail -n +2` if you want to drop that first line.

Comment: trying but get errors:
`$ drush @d6mg sqlq "SELECT type FROM node_type;"
ï»¿ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'drupal6_mg.node_type' doesn't exist
$ drush @d6mg sqlq "SELECT name FROM node_type;"
ï»¿ERROR 1146 (42S02) at line 1: Table 'drupal6_mg.node_type' doesn't exist
`

Comment: @webmaster_pf, I just checked this again, works fine. Do you have a table_prefix on this site? What does `drush sqlq "SHOW TABLES;"|grep type` give you?

Comment: yes i have prefix but your command give me a list of tables .this is the right command :drush sqlq "SHOW TABLES;"|grep content_type

Answer (score 5):

If you know how to do it in Drupal, you just need to use `drush eval`:

Drupal 6:

```
drush eval '$types = node_get_types(); foreach($types as $type => $object) { print $type . "\n"; }'
```

Drupal 7:

```
drush eval '$types = node_type_get_types(); foreach($types as $type => $object) { print $type . "\n"; }'
```

See this [list of drush commands](http://orga.cat/posts/most-useful-drush-commands) for other useful examples using `eval`.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a drush command named `content-type-list`. Create a module named `drush_content_types`, inside the `drush_content_types.drush.inc` file put this code:

```
<?php
/**
 * @file
 * Drush commands related to Content Types.
 */

/**
* Implements hook_drush_command().
*/
function drush_content_types_drush_command() {
  $items['content-type-list'] = array(
    'description' => dt("Show a list of available content types."),
    'aliases' => array('ctl'),
  );
  return $items;
}

/**
 * Callback for the content-type-list command.
 */
function drush_drush_content_types_content_type_list() {
  $content_types = array_keys(node_type_get_types());
  sort($content_types);

  drush_print(dt("Machine name"));
  drush_print(implode("\r\n", $content_types));
}
```

Install the module, run `drush cc drush` to clear the drush cache and use the command like this:

```
drush ctl
```

or

```
drush content-type-list
```

If you want add another alias to the command add elements to the aliases array like this:

```
'aliases' => array('ctl', 'all-content-types', 'act'),
```

And you can use this commands:

```
drush act
drush all-content-types
drush ctl
drush content-type-list
```

Always the output will be:

```
Machine name:
content 1
content 2
content...
content n
```

Answer (score 4):

**Drupal 9**

```bash
drush ev "print_r(array_keys(\Drupal\node\Entity\NodeType::loadMultiple()));"
```

Answer (score 0):

For a more rich, complete, report, you can use site_audit, which will give you content types, fields, and a ton of extra information

https://www.drupal.org/project/site_audit

Drutiny is as well a good tool, not necessarily for content types, but in order to get a ton of extra information from your site

https://drutiny.github.io/2.3.x/getting-started/